# Default selected node in jsf rich:tree

Tags: jsf, tree, richfaces

I'm creating a jsf which contains a rich:tree. When the tree is going to render, data is pulled from a database to render the tree.

Next to the tree is a chart. The charts content is linked to the selected node in the tree.

When the tree is rendered, no node is selected -> no chart.

Is it possible to select the root node as default selected node and how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `adviseNodeSelected` attribute of the tree.

> MethodBinding pointing at a method accepting an org.richfaces.component.UITree with return of java.lang.Boolean type. If returned value is: java.lang.Boolean. TRUE, a particular treeNode is selected; java.lang.Boolean.FALSE, a particular treeNode is unselected; null, a particular treeNode saves the current state

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tree.jsf?tab=info